# Let V be a vector space of dimension n. Prove that no set of n - 1 vectors can span V.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, span

I'm not sure I understand the question. As far as I understand it when it says vector space of dimension n, it signifies that there will be n amount of vectors; right? So basically it wants you to prove that a set of two vectors can't span a set of three vectors?

Comment: Hint: the [Dimension Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimension_theorem_for_vector_spaces).

Comment: the dimension is not the numbers of vectors in space!

Answer (score 1):

First, know the definition of dimension and basis.

> The *dimension* of a vector space is the number of vectors in any of its bases.
>
> A *basis* for a vector space is a set of vectors that is linearly independent and spans the space.

---

It is not solely about showing that a set of two vectors cannot span a set of three vectors, since this is possible if say a vector is a from the set of three vectors is a linear combination of the two vectors.

Instead, we have to take note of the definition given by a basis for a vector space. Reading closely, it is the maximal linearly independent set of vectors and the minimal spanning set of vectors for a vector space. Using these definitions properly, you can prove your problem via contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

Hint; Let V be a vector space of dimension n . Then any basis of V contains n vectors. And these n vectors span V and are linearly independent. Do you know of any thereom that relates span and linear independence ?

Comment: Citing the Dimension Theorem as Vadim sugested: Given a vector space V, any two linearly independent generating sets (in other words, any two bases) have the same cardinality. Given that any set that's n-1 dimension would have one less element would I be able to use this to prove? (sorry if I sound dense, linear algebra is hard for me, I just don't find it intuitive at all)